# Parsing iOS 6 emoji with regex

Tags: android, regex, utf-8, emoji

I'm trying to wrap my head around parsing emoji from iOS 6 using regex.

I want each occurrence of an emoji to be replaced by a spannable, where I replace the emoji code by it's image in my Resources. So far, I haven't been able to get it to work.

What I have so far:

```
static public Spannable getSpannable(String str) {
    Spannable spannable = spannableFactory.newSpannable(str);
    char c = str.charAt(0);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\ud83d\ude01-\ud83d\ude45])");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        if (mSpannables.get(m.group()) == null) {
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myApp.getAppContext().getResources(), R.drawable.u0033);
            ImageSpan imp = new ImageSpan(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 70, 70, false));
            mSpannables.put(m.group(), imp);
        }
        spannable.setSpan(mSpannables.get(m.group()), m.start(), m.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    return spannable;
}
```

(I realize this isn't production-ready yet; creating the pattern each time the function is called is a performance killer. I'm just trying to get the regex matching working.)

The current regex is matching a small number of emoji. I would like to factorize it as much as possible, and get the full emoji charset in it.

As soon as I try to factorize, it does not work anymore. For example, this does not work:

```
"\ud83d[\udc00-\uddff]"
```

Even less when I try

```
"[\ue000-\uf8ff]|\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|\ud83d[\udc00-\uddff]"
```

which should (if working) match every single emoji present in the charset.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php find emoji \[update existing code\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564068/php-find-emoji-update-existing-code)

Answer (score 1):

The Java regular expression engine behaves like a good Unicode regular expression engine should in that **it matches Unicode codepoints, not UTF-16 `char`s**.  You appear to be writing your pattern expecting the latter behavior.

Don't do this - instead, when specifying astral-plane characters in a Java regex, use hexadecimal notation for the full codepoint value.  For example, to match CLAPPING HANDS SIGN, use `\x{1f44f}`.

So your last regex (which would match the BMP Private Use Area, the Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs block, the Emoticons block, the Transport and Map Symbols block, the Alchemical Symbols block, and a fair bit of unallocated space in the SMP besides - are you sure you need to match all of those?) should be rendered as:

```
"[\ue000-\uf8ff]|[\\x{1f300}-\\x{1f7ff}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at the implementation of `addEmojis` in https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/rockerhieu/emojicon/EmojiconHandler.java

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score -1):

```
Pattern pUnicode6  = Pattern.compile("[\uD83C\uDC04-\uD83C\uDD9A]|([\uD83C\uDDE8-\uD83C\uDDFA][\uD83C\uDDE7-\uD83C\uDDFA])|[\uD83C\uDE01-\uD83D\uDEC0])");
```